# Нужно ли ставить запятую в предложении "Не знаю, как здесь, а в школе..."?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли ставить запятую в предложении "Не знаю, как здесь, а в школе..."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хотелось бы уточнить (так как запятых две):

Вы спрашиваете про нужность запятой перед противительным союзом ***а*** или перед придаточным предложением (отделяемым от главного)?

На всякий случай отвечаю про обе:

а) нужно;

б) нужно.

Comment: Сомневалась в запятой перед придаточным предложением (перед союзом "как", если говорить проще). 
Спасибо большое за ответ)

Comment: У нас же две основы: *<я> не знаю* и *<принято, заведено>* в школе...